# Integral of $\int \tan(x) \sec^3 {x}\, \text dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to find the integral of $$\int \tan x \sec^3 x dx$$

$$\int \tan x(1+\tan^2 x)\sec x\, dx$$

This gets me nowhere since I get a $\sec^2 x$ derivative with tan substitution so I try something else.

$$\int \frac {\sin x}{\cos x} \frac{1}{\cos^3x}  dx$$

$$\int \frac {\sin x}{\cos^4 x}  dx$$

$u = \cos x$ $du = -\sin x$

$$\int \frac {-1}{u^4} du$$

$$-1\int {u^{-4}} du$$

$$-1 \frac{u^{-3}}{3}$$
$$\frac{-1}{3\cos^3 x}$$

This for some reason is wrong.

Comment: Your calculation is correct except for the last two lines. The integration of $-u^{-4}$ is $u^{-3}/3$, not $-u^{-3}/3$.

Comment: You just missed a minus at the end.

Comment: (and for all of those constant-fans - add a +C)

Comment: Another method would be to note that $\tan x \, \sec^3 x = (\tan x \, \sec x)(\sec^2 x)$  and that the differential of $\sec x$ is $\tan x \, \sec x$. A method called spotting the presence of the derivative.

Comment: Detailed steps [here](https://www.sympygamma.com/input/?i=integrate%28tan%28x%29*sec%28x%29**3%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a $-$ sign in the denominator. $$\int x^{n} \ \text dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C$$ when $n \neq -1$.

So when $n=-4$ you get $$\int x^{-4} \ \text dx = -\frac{1}{3} \cdot x^{-3} +C$$

There is still an easier method of doing this: $$\int \tan{x}\cdot \sec^{3}(x) \ \text dx = \int \tan{x} \cdot \sec{x} \cdot \sec^{2}(x) \ \text dx = \int t^{2} \ \text dt$$ by putting $t=\sec{x}$.

Comment: to the downvoter why a downvote

Comment: @jordan: Great that you were able to come up with a solution on your own. Here is an exercise : $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x} \cdot \cos{x}}} \ dx$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{\sin(x)dx}{(\cos(x))^4}=-\int\frac{d(\cos(x))}{(\cos(x))^4}=\frac{1}{3(\cos(x))^3}+ C $$